# File copy and renaming

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, copy, rename

I want to copy below files from one location to another.
After copy file I want to add something in file name.

From C:\Users\Niki\Desktop*.csv
To C:\Users\Niki\reports\Final_*.csv

How would I do that?
I am using below command for this:

```
copy /-y "C:\Users\Niki\Desktop\*.csv" "%TargetFolder%"
```

Comment: what do you want to add (source, example)?

Comment: want to add "Final_" in file name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a batch file that should work:

```
@echo off
set "targetfolder=d:\backup"
for %%a in ("C:\Users\Niki\Desktop\*.csv") do (
copy /-y "%%a" "%TargetFolder%\Final_%%~nxa"
)
```

Comment: thx ..I also want to do same thing with below command. – call :CopyandRename "C:\Users\Niki\Desktop\report" "%TargetFolder%\"....there is a file in "Report" folder

Answer (score 2):

```
for %%x in ("C:\Users\Niki\Desktop\*.csv") do copy "%%~fx" "C:\Users\Niki\reports\Final_%%~nxx"
```

Comment: thx ..I also want to do same thing with below command. – call :CopyandRename "C:\Users\Niki\Desktop\report" "%TargetFolder%\"....there is a file in "Report" folder

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am misunderstanding your question but can you not just specify the file name at the end of your destination directory?

```
copy /-y "C:\Users\Niki\Desktop\xyz.csv" "%TargetFolder%\Final_xyz.csv"
```

Comment: @Chockleyc...when I'll run I woudn't know the file name "xyz.csv" is an example (variable file name)

Comment: copy /-y "C:\Users\Niki\Desktop\*.csv" "%TargetFolder%"...then code will be?

Comment: Ahh, alright I was misunderstanding your question then.  That is beyond my limited knowledge and it seems like you have other answers.  Good luck!